# How to get html table position

Tags: c#, html, html-table

I've an aspx page and that page has a table like below

```
<table id="tbl1" runat="server">
<tr>
<td>
Hello world
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to get the position of the table (x,y coordinates) from code behind (C#).

Is there any way to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**ASPX:**

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getPosition(elmID) {
            var elmPosition = $("#"+elmID).position();
            $("#<%= hdnPosition.ClientID%>").val(elmPosition.left + "," + elmPosition.top);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%= btnGetPosition.ClientID %>").click(function () {
                getPosition("tbl1");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmMain" runat="server">
    <table id="tbl1" runat="server">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Hello world
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPosition" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnGetPosition" runat="server" Text="Get position" 
        onclick="btnGetPosition_Click"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Codebehind:**

```
protected void btnGetPosition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string position = hdnPosition.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with many ways

1. add a placeholder and put your table at runtime:-

   ```
   <asp:placeholder id="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" xmlns:asp="#unknown">
   </asp:placeholder>
   ```
2. set CSS at runtime

   ```
   style1
   {
   position:absolute;
   left:100px; //Example
   top:150px; //Example
   }
   ```

   in CS code, use

   ```
   Table.CssClass = "style1";
   ```
3. You can use Control.Style Property to set style of a control:

   ```
   Table tbl = new Table();
   tbl.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position] = "Absolute";
   tbl.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top] = "10px";
   ```
4. If you want it in complete JavaScript. For example:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
   <title>Overlapping tables</title>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

   <style type="text/css" media="all">
   table.first
   {
       position: absolute;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;

       color: #000000;
       background-color: #ff0000;
       text-align: center;
   }

   table.second
   {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       position: relative;

       text-align: center;
       color: #00ff00;
       background-color: transparent;
   }

   </style>

   <script type="text/javascript"><!--

   onload = setPos;

   function setPos ()
   {
       var table_1 = new namedTable ('first_table');
       var table_2 = new namedTable ('second_table');

       table_2.style.top = table_1.style.top - 1;
       table_2.style.left = table_1.style.left - 1;
   }


   function namedTable(name)
   {

       if (document.getElementById)
       {
           this.obj = document.getElementById(name);
           this.style = document.getElementById(name).style;
       }
       else if (document.all)
       {
           this.obj = document.all[name];
           this.style = document.all[name].style;
       }
       else if (document.layers)
       {
           this.obj = document.layers[name];
           this.style = document.layers[name];
       }
   }

   //--></script>

   </head>
   <body>

   <table class="first" id="first_table">
   <tr>
       <td>
           <h1>TABLE</h1>
       </td>
   </tr>
   </table>

   <table class="second" id="second_table">
   <tr>
       <td>
           <h1>TABLE</h1>
       </td>
   </tr>
   </table>

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Notes:

1) The document still validates (both CSS and HTML) at w3.org.

2) It is tested in Mozilla and Internet Explorer.

3) By force of habit I use the doc-type xhtml1-strict.dtd, but you should
not use this doctype when publishing for Mozilla. Use HTML
transitional instead - or simply put in no header (which will let the
browsers run in Quirk mode, and be more lenient towards scripting
errors).

4)
If you further want to study this topic, here is a link to the most
precise and lightweight Javascript Positioning techniques I know of:

http://www.quirksmode.org/

Good luck!